# How to use the format value passed into the URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to use ,value => x function for a field. To autocomplete the box field.

So to do that, I'm doing the following :

```
new_company_path(@compy = @pars4)
```

Which permit me to save the value that I want into the URL. And this is working, I currently have my url.@compy

But now, I would like to use this value into my new_company view. I'd try a different method like:

```
<%= f.text_field :name, :value => @compy.to_s %>
```

But is still not working. I can see that the value is saved into a "format", but I don't now how to access it. So if you have any tricks to do that, it will be really helpful. Thanks for your time

Comment: Not a suggested way to do such things in rails, try `new_company_path(compy: @pars4)` instead. Then access the value in your views using `params[:compy]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use like

```
new_company_path(compy: @compy)
```

You will get this value by `params[:compy]`

you should use like

```
<%= f.text_field :name, :value => params[:compy] %>
```

Comment: Cool, muchas gracias @Sunny, that's exactly what i'm searching for. Clear & concise, if every responses was like that, i would be rich !! Thanks again